# How to navigate through JSON object that has numbers?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm working with a JSON object that looks like this:

```
entire
  text
    body
      div
        0
        1
        2
        ...
        30
```

Currently, how I access the contents within 0-30 is with the following code where I just for each over everything once I get to the div's contents. The reasoning is that for some reason numbers don't work, so I can't do entire.text.body.div.0

```
entire.text.body.div.forEach(function(example) {
    // do stuff here

});
```

Why do I ask? Right now I am running into a problem when I am trying to do something similar above when trying to access the contents of the same JSON object. In particular, with the following JSON, I am trying to get the attribute's value, and do something similar as above, but it's not working.

```
entire
  text
    body
      div
        0
          p
            0
            1
               attribute: value
        1
        2
        ...
        30
```

Code I try using.. but again it doesn't work, and I am not able to access the attribute/value.

```
entire.text.body.div.forEach(function(example) {
    // do stuff here

    example.p.forEach(function(anotherExample) {



});
```

Comment: can I see your data as actual json format?

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` to access them - for example:

```
var obj = {1:"a"}; 
console.log(obj[1]); // outputs "a"
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

> Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation.
>
> `object.property` or
> `object["property"]`

Typical uses for bracket notation is accessing properties of arrays or arrays like objects, or of working with an object property which name is a variable.

Of specific practical application of bracket notation with code, consider a function that iterates through the properties of an object, performing some function on each property -

```
var john = { 
    firstName: "John", 
    lastName: "Smith", 
    age: 33, 
    employer: { 
        name: "ABC Corp", 
    },
    0:"numeral zero"
}

function print(obj) { 
    console.log(obj); 
}

function walk(obj, fn) { 
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(prop) { 
        if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') { 
            walk(obj[prop], fn); 
        } else { 
            fn(obj[prop]); 
        }
    });
}

walk(john, print);
```

Output -

```
jdphenix@jdphenix-desktop:~/Desktop$ nodejs test1.js
numeral zero
John
Smith
33
ABC Corp
```

Comment: This looks promising. I will try this and report back. Thank you.